# sha256 implementation in javascript

Tags: javascript, sha

I'm currently trying to implement sha256 from a scratch.

I'm implementing ch() function whose definition is
     `ch(x,y,z) = (x&y) ^ (~x&z)`

(`&`:indicate and gate, `^`:indicate xor gate, `~`:is negate)

I implemented like this:

```
function ch(x,y,z){
 (x&y) ^ (~x&z)
}
```

but after I implemented it, when I saw some other implementation such ashttp://point-at-infinity.org/jssha256/, the implementation is like this (below)

```
function SHA256_Ch(x, y, z) {
  return z ^ (x & (y ^ z));
}
```

what is this conversion?

can I obtain the same result from wikipedia's?

Could you tell me the path ?

### ---------------------------------------------------------

Thank you for answeing!

> ch() stands for choose: x chooses y or z. When x is 0, z is chosen,
>   and when x is 1, y is chosen

This is a critical sentence for me.
I wanted to know how the desiner find second form ch function.

but I guess, if I obtain the view of your advise then, that is obvious.

if a designer of sha256 want to use ch function like it, that makes sense.when x is zero, y is 0, and z is left, because x and z is connected with xor gate,and x and y is connected with and gate.when x is one, y is y and z is nothing, because there are two z connected with xor gate;

I should start my guess from the perspective of the one who structured SHA256 algorythm.

Thanks for teaching!!

kouji

Comment: [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: Dear mitch. 

I'm sorry.

 Althogh you helped me a lot. I was rude to you, because of my ignorance. 

I'll accept your graceful answer, as you suggest.

 Is it worked?

Thank you for advises!!

Comment: You weren't rude. Just a new stackoverflower!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you write out the truth table for x, y, z and the 2 expressions, you will see that they are **identical**.

In both cases (I've left out the intermediate results for brevity):

```
x  y  z  (x&y)^(~x&z)  z^(x&(y^z))
0  0  0  0             0
0  0  1  1             1
0  1  0  0             0  
0  1  1  1             1  
1  0  0  0             0  
1  0  1  0             0  
1  1  0  1             1  
1  1  1  1             1
```

`ch()` stands for *choose*:  `x` chooses `y` or `z`. When `x` is `0`, `z` is chosen, and when `x` is `1`, `y` is chosen

The second form uses 1 less bitwise operation; but I'd guess that any speed improvement would be implementation specific.